# How do I define an Error Class?

Tags: python, exception, python-2.7

Python 2.7.3

I got the following error when I ran `SillyWalk.getGroups(user_id = user)` for a user who, like the parrot, is no more.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python\API\getgroups.py", line 32, in <module>
        Grp = SillyWalk.getGroups(user_id = user)
    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\SillyWalkapi-1.4.2-py2.7.egg\SillyWalkapi\__init__.py", line 349, in handler
        parse_format=args['format'], **args)
    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\SillyWalkapi-1.4.2-py2.7.egg\SillyWalkapi\__init__.py", line 435, in __wrap_in_parser
        return parser(self, data)
    File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\SillyWalkapi-1.4.2-py2.7.egg\SillyWalkapi\__init__.py", line 278, in parse_etree
        raise SillyWalkError(u'Error: %(code)s: %(msg)s' % err.attrib)
SillyWalkError: Error: 1: User not found
```

I tried to fix the problem by putting a `try ... except` statement in:

```
try:
    Grp = SillyWalk.getGroups(user_id = user)
    g = 0
    for group in Grp.find('groups').findall('group'):
        g += 1
        u_ID  = user
        g_ID  = group.get('_ID')
        gName  = "" # group.get('name')
        HasParrot    = group.get('HasParrot')
        Priv   = group.get('Priv')
        Mbr    = group.get('members')
        threads = group.get('threads')

        tup = '{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}\t{5}\t{6}\n'.format(u_ID, g_ID, gName.encode('utf-8'), HasParrot, Priv, Mbr, threads)
        OutFile.write(tup.encode('utf-8'))
except SillyWalkError:
    tup = '{0}\tNo Records Found\n'.format(u_ID)
    OutFile.write(tup.encode('utf-8'))
```

but it gave me an undefined error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python\API\getgroups.py", line 47, in <module>
        except SillyWalkError:
NameError: name 'SillyWalkError' is not defined
>>>
```

This is my first attempt to write an exception class, so could someone please show me how to do it?  The `SillyWalk.getGroups` has a dozen or so different error numbers, for various error reasons.  Do I need a case for each one?

I'll be forever in your debt!  (You'll never collect anything from me, but I'll still owe it to you!)

BTW: while rooting about in the guts of my script, could someone show me how to fix my `gName` problem, so I don't need to null it out?  It keeps giving me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Python\API\getgroups.py", line 44, in <module>
        OutFile.write(tup.encode('utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 54: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: you might want to split this into several questions

Comment: Change the `except SillyWalkError:` to `except SillyWalk.SillyWalkError:` because the name is defined in that module's namespace.

Comment: @martineau:  with `except SillyWalk.SillyWalkError:` I get rid of the "undefined" error, but I get the `File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\SillyWalkapi-1.4.2-py2.7.egg\SillyWalkapi\__init__.py", line 278, in parse_etree
    raise SillyWalkError(u'Error: %(code)s: %(msg)s' % err.attrib)` error

Comment: Well, I was just guessing, but it looks like you got the basic idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NameError: name 'SillyWalkError' is not defined` just indicates that the name `SillyWalkError` is not defined. It's nothing specific to exception handling or writing an exception class.

It looks like you just haven't imported the name `SillyWalkError` into the module that's trying to catch the exception; the error you were getting without the `except` indicates that the exception class itself is working fine.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't anything that I can import.  The error is coming from the server.  I assume that I'll have to incorporate the error definitions for my end.  Is that wrong?

Comment: You need to extend `Exception` in your class `SillyWalkError`

Comment: @DeinaUnderhill The traceback clearly shows that `File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\SillyWalkapi-1.4.2-py2.7.egg\SillyWalkapi\__init__.py", line 278, in parse_etree` is executing the line `raise SillyWalkError(u'Error: %(code)s: %(msg)s' % err.attrib)1. There's no way it could do that if `SillyWalkError` wasn't a name defined in the scope where that line is executed. The usual thing is for exception types to be defined in some module's global scope, so they can be imported along with other classes/functions/whatever, so that client code can catch exceptions of that type.

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee The exception **is** being raised. There is no problem with the `SillylWalkError` class that is visible from the information being provided. @DeinaUnderhill is only having a problem catching it.

Comment: I'm having trouble capturing the error, and continuing beyond it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, sports fans!

At least the first question I had on this was a result of one of my many blonde moments! [image: blonde moments!]

I was using `except SillyWalk.SillyWalkError ...` instead of `except SillyWalk***api***.SillyWalkError ...`

Thanks to everyone who helped!